# Why can't "os.path.getsize" work with a regular string

Tags: python

When I run the following everything works fine.

```
import os 
fileSize=os.path.getsize("/Users/Richard/Desktop/Schedule.doc")
print fileSize
```

When I run the following however i get the error "no such file or directory". Does os.path.getsize not accept variable stings? 
I want as the following because it will be easier to copy, past and edit in multiple programs.

```
import os    
fileName ="Schedule.doc"
path = os.path.join('Users','Richard', 'Desktop')
filelocation = os.path.join(path, fileName)
fileSize=os.path.getsize(filelocation)
print fileSize
```

Comment: Does the indentation look like that in your actual file? Indentation matters in Python. Also, you really ought to be more specific than "it does not run".

Comment: The indent were not in my actual file

Comment: At least, check that `path` actually holds a valid file path by `print path` ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try printing `filelocation`. You'll find that it doesn't start with a slash. The `os.path.join` commands you issued built a relative path, so Python is looking for `Users/Richard/Desktop/Schedule.doc` relative to the current directory.

`os.path.join('/Users', ...)`, with the first argument starting with a slash, should get you an absolute path.